# Failed to load UI5 component for navigation intent: Error: adding object "component" with duplicate id

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have an issue while accessing a Fiori application for the second time on the launchpad. The error message I am receiving is:

> Failed to load UI5 component for navigation intent
> #ZUI5_PROMO_MANU-display - Error: adding object "component" with duplicate id 'application-ZUI5_PROMO_MANU-display-component'

I have this in my `Component.js`:

```
destroy: function() {
  this._oErrorHandler.destroy(); //only if you have one
  // call the base component's destroy function
  UIComponent.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

What is causing the duplicate ID error and how do I fix it?

Comment: How and where is the UI5 element with the ID suffix "`component`" created?

Comment: Does your application have `templateShareable: 'false'` somewhere? (It should be `templateShareable: false` without wrapping with single quotes)

Comment: Are you using `thatComponentContainer.setComponent(myCreatedComponent)` somewhere? If so, what does `thatComponentContainer.getLifecycle()` return?

Comment: Are you removing an element with `thatManagedObject.removeXYZ()` somewhere?

Comment: With which SAPUI5 and OpenUI5 versions is the app running? (Press [Ctrl] + [Shift] + [Left Alt] + [P] to get the versions)

Comment: Thank you @BoghyonHoffmann,

I solved the problem by deleting this line:
// this._Error_Handler.destroy();