# FLP Duplicate Component ID

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

We are facing an issue, where clicking on the tile twice in the same session is getting us an error in console saying :

> Error: Error: adding object "component" with duplicate id

We have tried to implement Destroy function as follows in the component.js but it doesn't seem to be working.

If someone has faced any similar issue, can you please support here?

We have tried implementing this function in Component.js

The component is still there when we are exiting the app for the first time. I tried to destroy the `this._oErrorHandler` manually, but that also didn't fix the issue.

```
destroy: function() {
                        if (this._oErrorHandler) {
                            this._oErrorHandler.destroy()
                        }
                        if (this.oRouteHandler) {
                            this.oRouteHandler.destroy()
                        }
                        sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments)
                    },
```

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/75697252/5846045. Hence the same questions asked in the comment there also apply here. Could you answer them? We need more information.

Comment: Additionally, open the devtool (F12), rerun the FLP app with the URL parameter sap-ui-debug=true, reproduce the "duplicate id" error, and share the callstack that led to the error.

Comment: Hello @BoghyonHoffmann, Here are the answers to your questions 1. On component instantiation the id is created. 2. No templateShareable is with quotes 3. No component container used 4. No removal 5. SAP UI5 v1.108.10 openUI5 v1.108.6

Comment: Additionally i am seeing this error while closing the app,  exception when trying to close sapui5 application with id 'XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXX_XXXXXX' This error must be fixed in order for FLP to operate properly.
 - TypeError: this._destroyCreatedInstances is not a function

Comment: It is fixed now, we had multiple instances of destroy function and it was breaking the event in component.js.

Comment: Please update the question with the callstack (e.g. screenshot) to the until the call `_destroyCreatedInstances`.

Answer (score 0):

So the quick solution to this issue is implementing a destroy function on the component.js file

```
destroy: function () {
        UIComponent.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments);
    }
```

Comment: With the above lines of code, you could then simply remove the entire custom `destroy` implementation since it's the same thing. The solution is not implementing a custom `destroy` function but resolving the error uncaught "TypeError: this._destroyCreatedInstances is not a function" which is raised when the application is destroyed (e.g. when navigating back to the FLP home)